# How to use Injection Annotation

Tags: eclipse, jsf, cdi

Until to now i use (like beginner) JSF. Usually I make xhtml page and backend bean. And in backing bean I use annotation like @ManagedBean, @SessionScoped, @Application and so on. i think that is annotation for javax.faces.bean, if it is correctly that is faces annotations.

Bath I find one tutorial on internet where one guy use annotation like @Model an most interesting in backand bean He uses the `@Inject` annotation. I find that is very useful. He use injection for Logger class and in same bean can use methods from that class. Something like these:

```
@Model
public class FileUploadBean {
    @Inject Logger log;
    private Part file;

    public void upload(){
        ...
    }
}
```

Are there he use enterprise java, maybe CDI and how I can use this annotation. Because when i write `@Inject` in my Backing bean have message that is ambiguous annotation.
 What i have to know and about what?

I working with eclipse and glassfish!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're talking about the `javax.enterprise.Inject` annotation. See the [cdi](/questions/tagged/cdi) tag wiki page for some basic information. The only thing you'd need to have is the corresponding `import` statement.

A word of warning: if you already have a project with JSF beans, note that most scope annotations (`@SessionScoped`, `@RequestScoped`, ...) have a CDI equivalent that has the same name. Make sure you `import` the correct annotation or you'll find that your "session bean" suddenly has only request scope.

**See also:**

[Weld Reference](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html)

[JEE6 CDI Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giwhl.html)